# How to check if a string only contains digits/numerical characters

Tags: bash

How can I check if `MyVar` contains *only* digits with an `if` statement with BASH. By digits I am referring to 0-9.

ie:

```
if [[ $MyVar does contain digits ]]  <-- How can I check if MyVar is just contains numbers
then
 do some maths with $MyVar
else
 do a different thing
fi
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

It prints `ok` if the first argument contains only digits and `no` otherwise. You could call it with: `./yourFileName.sh inputValue`

Answer (score 16):

```
[[ $myvar =~ [^[:digit:]] ]] || echo All Digits
```

Or, if you like the `if-then` form:

```
if [[ $myvar =~ [^[:digit:]] ]]
then
    echo Has some nondigits
else
    echo all digits
fi
```

In olden times, we would have used `[0-9]`.  Such forms are not unicode safe.  The modern unicode-safe replacement is `[:digit:]`.

Comment: `if [[ $MyVar =~ [0-9] ]]` is this the same?

Comment: 1.) `$MyVar =~ [0-9]` tests for at least one digit within MyVar.  As I understand your goal, you want to find out if it is _all_ digits.  Hence my inverted form.  2.) `[0-9]` used to work.  With modern unicode, you can't trust it  That is why I used `[:digit:]`

Comment: What if `$myvar` is empty?

Comment: @selurvedu Unicode contains many digit/numerical characters other than 0123456789.  Also, note that the interpretation of ranges like `0-9` is subject to the vagaries of locales and collation orders.

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to test in a POSIX compliant way, you can use either:

```
expr string : regex        ## returns length of string if both sides match
```

or

```
expr match string regex    ## behaves the same
```

For example to test if `$myvar` is all digits:

```
[ $(expr "x$myvar" : "x[0-9]*$") -gt 0 ] && echo "all digits"
```

**Note:** `'x'` prepended to the variable and expression to protect against test of empty-string throwing error. To use the `length` returned by the test, don't forget to subtract `1` which represents the `'x'`.

In `if-then-else` form, here is a short script that tests whether the first argument to the script contains all digits:

```
#!/bin/sh

len=$(expr "x$1" : "x[0-9]*$")  ## test returns length if $1 all digits
let len=len-1                   ## subtract 1 to compensate for 'x'

if [ $len -gt 0 ]; then         ## test if $len -gt 0 - if so, all digits
    printf "\n '%s' : all digits, length: %d chars\n" "$1" $len
else
    printf "\n '%s' : containes characters other than [0-9]\n" "$1"
fi
```

**Example Output**

```
$ sh testdigits.sh 265891

 '265891' : all digits, length: 6 chars

$ sh testdigits.sh 265891t

 '265891t' : contains characters other than [0-9]
```

The bash regular expression test `[[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]` is fine, I use it, but it is a **bashism** (limited to the bash shell). If you are concerned with portability, the POSIX test will work in any POSIX compliant shell.

Answer (score 2):

For Bash, another option, maybe less expensive than regex match (I did not make performance tests), is to use  `pattern substitution` to replace all digits with empty string, and test if the resulting string is empty.

```
if [[ -z ${var//[0-9]} ]]; then      # or ${var//[[:digit:]]}
   echo "only digits"
else
   echo "not only digits"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple! just use expression option in grep
The below solution echo's the variable and checks if it contains only digits

```
if [[ $(echo $var | grep -E "^[[:digit:]]{1,}$") ]]
then
    echo "var contains only digits"
else
    echo "var contains other characters apart from digits"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep expression solution without [[ ]], for wider shell compatability:

```
if [ "$(echo $var | grep -E "^[0-9]{1,}$")" ]; then echo "digits only"; then
    echo "var contains digits only"
else
    echo "var contains digits and/or other characters"
fi
```